# Force Download of image with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to download a saved image after an ajax call. I have a canvas on the site that I am sending to a php file. I already managed to save a temporary image to the server but I want to have a download dialogue after that.

My PHP so far:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');
$img = $_REQUEST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

$quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
```

My javascrpt:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./ajax/base64ToImage.php",
data: { 
    imgBase64: dataURL
}
}).done(function(o) {
    console.log('saved'); 
    console.log(o); 
});
```

The file is saved correctly but I only get back an empty string. How do I force a download in that call?

Comment: I've more or less got the same case recently with an Excel file. I've just gave the url of my file to javascript `document.location = myFilePath` to force the download. I hope its help.

Comment: Have you tried `readfile($fileURL);` ?